# Apply filter in Dictionary of object array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, filter

I have an class of properties named "EpisodeInfoData"

```
class EpisodeInfoData {
    var episodeId = ""
    var episodeName = ""
}
```

I have store objects of these class into an dictionary whose first element is an "String" and another element is an array of "EpisodeInfoData" class objects

```
var episodes    = Dictionary<String, [EpisodeInfoData]>()

let infoObj1 = EpisodeInfoData()
infoObj1.episodeId           = "1"
infoObj1.episodeName         = "one"

let infoObj2 = EpisodeInfoData()
infoObj2.episodeId           = "2"
infoObj2.episodeName         = "two"

let infoObj3 = EpisodeInfoData()
infoObj3.episodeId           = "3"
infoObj3.episodeName         = "three"

let infoObj4 = EpisodeInfoData()
infoObj4.episodeId           = "4"
infoObj4.episodeName         = "four"

let infoObj5 = EpisodeInfoData()
infoObj5.episodeId           = "5"
infoObj5.episodeName         = "five"

let infoObj6 = EpisodeInfoData()
infoObj6.episodeId           = "6"
infoObj6.episodeName         = "six"

let infoObj7 = EpisodeInfoData()
infoObj7.episodeId           = "7"
infoObj7.episodeName         = "seven"

let infoObj8 = EpisodeInfoData()
infoObj8.episodeId           = "8"
infoObj8.episodeName         = "eight"

episodes["season1"] = [infoObj1,infoObj2,infoObj3,infoObj4]
episodes["season2"] = [infoObj5,infoObj6,infoObj7,infoObj8]
```

I want to get the name of season in "episodes" Dictionary whose episodeName is "eight". I have try to apply filter on it it was not working.

Can any some one suggest me anything to find the result using filters without using filters.

Thank You in advance

Comment: if I have name of the "season" then it is working
 "let temp = episodes["season1"]!.filter { $0.episodeId == "8" }"
but if I have only the episode id  then I tried this
"let temp = episodes.filter { $0.1.filter { $0.episodeId == "8"} }"

Comment: Hey Avinash, welcome to Stack Overflow. I made some improvements to your code, and I show I did them, step by step. Check it out [here](http://pastebin.com/bjTGLt56).

Comment: Alexander  thank you for the improvements. I really appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

had to add another answer thanks to those who down votes without really helping out.

try this

```
if let episode = (episodes.filter { $0.1.contains { $0.episodeName == "eight" } }).first {
    print(episode.0) // season2
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much koropok. this is like life saving solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [working solution](http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/57f2097f3297c15aa03ddec4).

```
struct EpisodeInfoData {
    let episodeId: String
    let episodeName: String
}

let episodes = [
    "season1": [
        EpisodeInfoData(
            episodeId: "1",
            episodeName: "one"
        ),
        EpisodeInfoData(
            episodeId: "2",
            episodeName: "two"
        ),
        EpisodeInfoData(
            episodeId: "3",
            episodeName: "three"
        ),
        EpisodeInfoData(
            episodeId: "4",
            episodeName: "four"
        ),
    ],

    "season2": [
        EpisodeInfoData(
            episodeId: "5",
            episodeName: "five"
        ),
        EpisodeInfoData(
            episodeId: "6",
            episodeName: "six"
        ),
        EpisodeInfoData(
            episodeId: "7",
            episodeName: "seven"
        ),
        EpisodeInfoData(
            episodeId: "8",
            episodeName: "eight"
        )
    ]
]

let desiredName = "eight"

let result = episodes.filter{ _, seasonEpisodes in
    return seasonEpisodes.contains{ $0.episodeName == desiredName }
}.map{ key, value in return key}

print(result)
```

The episodes dictionary is first filtered. Key-value pairs in the dictionary are only kept if the value (the `seasonEpisodes` Array) contains an episode with the `desiredName`. Then, those key-value pairs are mapped, and only the keys (the season names) are returned.